# IE7 Z-index problem

Tags: internet-explorer-7, z-index

Problem site: [www.basing.com/problem/index.html](http://www.basing.com/problem/index.html)

If you hover over the items in the list on the left you should see a nice popup showing the remaining characters of the text.

However, this doesn't work in IE 7. Does anyone have any ideas why not, or suggestions on how I could go about fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: Rather than forcing me to open your webpage, view the source, figure out where exactly you placed the code for this little effect, and then attempt to muddle through that code for the response, could you do some of that legwork for me? Like tell us what technologies you're using for the roll-over popup, and post the relevant code? Also, why are you convinced that this is a z-index problem?

Comment: Hi, i'm not using any technologie, just plain old css. It's a z-index problem because the popup works in the other browsers and the popup doesn't popup over it's container.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug about z-index on IE <= 7, when you use z-index when you mix absolute and relative positionned DOM elements you have to invert the z-index properties so that the lower will appear on top of the higher.

See http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug or http://www.shawnpreisz.com/css/z-index-internet-explorer-7-ie7 for another solution.

There is about a million post about this bug on the internet.

Comment: It's definitely not that bug because I'm quit aware of that bug and encounter it all the time. This is a bug that has something to do with the z-index but i can't pinpoint what exactly.